# error running server Django syntax error

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to get through a Django tutorial and I'm running into a syntax error when I try to run manage.py runserver. The error is below.

```
(C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\django  
tutorials\mysite>manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function         
check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001705F6D48C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\django tutorials\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 22
]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

mysite\urls.py is below. I'm not sure what is wrong with the syntax, or why it's pointing to the bracket.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')]
```

Comment: line 22 please,
May be you missing " , "

Comment: The traceback says the error is on line 22. Your 5 line snippet does not show what the problem is.

Comment: Yes it says line 22 but those lines are the whole urls.py program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a list type for urlpatterns.
Leave a comma at the end of the list:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He _is_ using list for `urlpatterns`, and other than personal style and convenience, there's no reason to include the trailing comma. It certainly isn't going to solve his problem.

Comment: found the answer, actually was in a different urls.py, didn't close a parentheses.